# checking whether FB connect upgrade is fixed?

Tags: facebook

I received the following notice on Friday:

> As part of our continued efforts to migrate all apps to OAuth 2.0, we
>   opted in all apps using the new JavaScript SDK to OAuth 2.0 this
>   afternoon at 11am PT and reverted at 1:30pm because we noticed that
>   your app has not migrated. Please ensure that you have set the oauth
>   param in FB.init to true and that you are using FB.getAuthResponse to
>   obtain the access token.

Questions:

1. I've got several testing sites that I've built, and the email doesn't specify what site(s) its referring to. My main site, janglo.net, should be compatible as far as I know. Can someone please confirm what apps and sites need fixing?
2. is there any online tool I can use to check whether the issue is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Check all your applications - there is no magic tool that will verify/check/do the work for you.  As it says in the email - all you have to do is check that the `oauth` parameter is set to true in your `FB.init` call